# Detect if web app is running in NWJS

Tags: require, node-webkit

I am creating a web app which I plan to deliver both from a standard web site and as an NWJS standalone application. In NWJS, I can use the `require` command, but not in a browser. I can wrap my command in an `if` statement:

```
<script>
  if (typeof require === "function") {require('nwjs-osx-menu')(window)}
</script>
```

Are there other ways that would be considered better practice?

---

EDIT: following @Kuf's suggestion

```
<script>
  if (typeof require === "function") {
    try{
      require('nwjs-osx-menu')(window)
    } catch (error) {}
  }
</script>
```

Comment: while that can work it relies on an external module, while I checked for 'nw.gui' which is node-webkit internal module, so this function will work even if you didn't load any modules at all.

Comment: Ah! I understand your technique now. My aim is to load 'nwjs-osx-menu' if the app is running in NW.js, and to ignore it if the app is running in a browser. Your goal is to determine if the app is running in NW.js or not. Bonus question: is `var result = false;` necessary in your code?

Comment: Good catch, and now it is my turn :)  the `if (typeof require === "function")` part is redundant as it will throw an exception if the require is not defined

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

If the only difference is loading that library then your code seems fine.

**original post**

There is a web client require module so that might be a bit risky. I used the following:

```
function is_nwjs(){
    try{
        return (typeof require('nw.gui') !== "undefined");
    } catch (e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`process.__nwjs` 
if nwjs exist, the value will **1**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My limited understanding is that if `process` is defined, you are in NWJS, and have access to fields such as `process.versions['nw-flavor']`.

Comment: Your approach seems to get close, but while testing the `process.versions` object was empty for me.